# "Yeah Right" expression

Tags: expressions

Where does "Yeah right" come from? Can it be used in a formal writing? If not, what is a good alternative?

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Yes", "Yeah", "Yep"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1954/yes-yeah-yep)

Comment: @kiamlaluno - I think this one is different. See @Robusto's answer below.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

"Yeah, right!" is an example of [irony](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/irony). Irony is the use of a word or phrase to mean exactly the opposite of its literal sense. Here it would also qualify as [sarcasm](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/sarcasm). It would be understood to mean "No f@$*ing way!"

You would definitely not use it in formal writing, unless that composition was a treatise on slang or some other academic discourse on language.

Comment: Nice answer. But is it always irony though? Sometimes I say "yeah, right!" when I genuinely meant to agree with something that the other person said. Can I be misinterpreted?

Comment: Yes, a lot would depend on intonation. But if you detect any sarcasm at all — and that is a very subjective thing, involving tone of voice, facial expression, etc. — it is most likely being used in the negative sense.

Answer (score 6):

There's also a joke (that as far as I know can be applied to other languages as well with similar constructions; the Greek equivalent «Ναι, καλά» comes to mind for some strange reason :) where the teacher explains that there are times and languages where a double-negative has positive meaning ("Can't say I didn't see you") or it can keep a negative meaning ("Haven't done nothin!"), but there is no known case of a double-positive having a negative meaning, at which point the smart-alec of the class says:

“Yeah, right.”

Answer (score 2):

Alternative in formal writing could be

*I strongly disbelieve that statement*

or

Our company plans to take over facebook medio 2011

You: "That sounds inconceivable"

Answer (score 1):

> Yeah, right

could also be interpreted as another variation of

> [I know, right](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2470/what-does-i-know-right-mean)?

It entirely depends on inflection when speaking.  When written, if the ending punctuation is an exclamation

> Yeah, right!

you could infer the meaning to be ironic, whereas if the ending punctuation was a question mark

> Yeah, right?

you could infer the acceptance-seeking meaning.

Regardless, neither is appropriate for formal writing.