# Difference between "yup" and "yes"

Tags: differences

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Yes”, “Yeah”, “Yep”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1954/yes-yeah-yep)

What is the difference between *yup* and *yes*? Most of the time I use *yup* instead of *yes*.

Comment: Voting to close on the grounds any cursory search will reveal that "yup" (like "yep", "yeah", etc.) is slang/informal. Is it meaningful to ask the difference between using a slang word and the equivalent "standard" form?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*[Yup](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/yup)* and its [more common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=yup%2Cyep&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1950&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3) variant *[Yep](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/yep)* are informal ways of saying *Yes*.

The only difference is one of formality.  Use *Yup* only in informal (casual) settings; not, say, in a business meeting.

Answer (score 4):

*Yup* is the slang (informal) alternative to *Yes*. You shouldn't use it in formal cases.