# Why is "yeah" considered unprofessional?

Tags: formality

I have read in many places on the Internet that "yeah" is considered unprofessional. And that using "yes" is preferred and considered more formal. What is the reason behind it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [When is it appropriate to use "Yeah" and "Yep" as variants of the word "Yes"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1954/when-is-it-appropriate-to-use-yeah-and-yep-as-variants-of-the-word-yes)

Comment: Doesn't your own language have an equivalent meaning in ways to say yes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because it is informal and colloquial.

> **[yeah](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/yeah)** *adv. Informal* Yes.
>
> **[yeah](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=yeah&allowed_in_frame=0)** American English, colloquial, by 1863, from drawling pronunciation of yes.

---

You can check this similar question as well:

[When is it appropriate to use "Yeah" and "Yep" as variants of the word "Yes"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1954/when-is-it-appropriate-to-use-yeah-and-yep-as-variants-of-the-word-yes)

Answer (score 1):

Because "yeah" is an informal and almost lazy way of saying yes. In yeah,you are not pronouncing the word yes correctly.